# The same result for different parameters

Tags: bash

I have a strange situation. For different parameters I always get the same result

```
function test
{
  while getopts 'c:S:T:' opt ; do
    case "$opt" in
      c) STATEMENT=$OPTARG;;
      S) SCHEMA=$OPTARG;;
      T) TABLE=$OPTARG;;      
    esac
  done  
    echo "$STATEMENT, $SCHEMA, $TABLE"      
}

test -c CREATE -S schema1 -T tabela1
test -c TRUNCATE -S schema2 -T tabela2
test -c DROP -S schema3 -T tabela3
```

Result:

```
CREATE, schema1, tabela1
CREATE, schema1, tabela1
CREATE, schema1, tabela1
```

What is failed in my script?

Comment: I just ran your script without an issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In bash, you need to localize the $OPTIND variable.

```
function test () {
    local OPTIND
```

Otherwise it's global and the next call to `getopts` returns false (i.e. all arguments processed). Consider localizing the other variables, too, if they're not used outside of the function.

You can also just set it to zero.